# Retrieving reddit posts with Django

Tags: python, django, praw

As a way of learning Python/Django, I'm trying to recreate reddit in Django using PRAW, but I'm running into a few issues. Currently, I have my app configured to connect to reddit and retrieve the top 10 posts from the home page in my IndexView class, but this is causing problems when I try to add fields in my `Posts` model then use `makemigrations`. Even when I delete everything out of my database from django admin, if I add a field to my model, then use `python manage.py makemigrations`, I frequently get an error that says `no such column: post_is_self` or something similar. When I comment out the new field, reboot the django server, the posts are back in the database, even though I haven't accessed the index of my app in the meantime.

I believe that the problem is with the way I'm populating the database. I want to retrieve the latest top 10 posts when the user goes to the index of my app, but now adding new fields is incredibly difficult. It seems as if it's retrieving posts when it shouldn't, and this is causing problems when a new field is added to the model and makemigrations is being called.

Here is my IndexView class:

```
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'reddit/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'top_posts'

    #Get top 10 posts from the front page
    pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent = 4)
    r = praw.Reddit(user_agent = user_agent)
    front_page = r.get_front_page(limit = thing_limit)
    for thing in front_page:
        # Format timestamp
        utc_dt = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(thing.created_utc).replace(
            tzinfo=pytz.utc
        )
        local_dt = local_tz.normalize(utc_dt.astimezone(local_tz))
        post = Post(
            id = thing.id,
            post_title = thing.title, 
            post_submitted_on = local_dt,
            post_upvotes = thing.ups,
            post_downvotes = thing.downs,
            post_score = thing.score,
            post_submitter = thing.author,
            post_comment_count = thing.num_comments,
            post_permalink = thing.permalink,
            post_url = thing.url,
            post_subreddit = thing.subreddit,
            post_subreddit_id = thing.subreddit_id,
            post_thumbnail = thing.thumbnail,
        )
        if thing.is_self:
            post.post_selftext = thing.selftext
        post.save()

    def get_queryset(self):
        # Return top 10 stories, in descending order by score
        return Post.objects.all().order_by('-post_score')[:10]
```

Edit: ...and my `Post` model:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.post_title
    id = models.CharField(
        verbose_name='Post ID',
        primary_key=True,
        max_length=200
    )
    post_title = models.CharField(
        verbose_name='Post title',
        max_length=200
    )
    post_submitted_on = models.DateTimeField(
        verbose_name='Submitted on',
        null=True
    )
    post_upvotes = models.IntegerField(
        verbose_name='Upvotes',
        null=True
    )
    post_downvotes = models.IntegerField(
        verbose_name='Downvotes',
        null=True
    )
    post_score = models.IntegerField(
        verbose_name='Score',
        null=True
    )
    post_submitter = models.CharField(
        verbose_name='Submitted by',
        null=True,
        max_length=15
    )
    post_subreddit_id = models.CharField(
        verbose_name='Subreddit ID',
        null=True,
        max_length=200
    )
    post_comment_count = models.IntegerField(
        verbose_name='Number of comments', 
        null=True
    )
    post_permalink = models.URLField(
        verbose_name='Permalink',
        null=True
    )
    post_url = models.URLField(
        verbose_name='Post URL',
        null=True
    )
    post_subreddit = models.CharField(
        verbose_name='Subreddit',
        null=True,
        max_length=200
    )
    post_thumbnail = models.URLField(
        verbose_name='Thumbnail URL',
        null=True
    )
    #post_is_self = models.BooleanField(
    #   verbose_name='Is self post?',
    #   null=True,
    #   default=False
    #)
    post_selftext = models.TextField(
        verbose_name='Self post text',
        max_length=40000,
        default='Not a self post'
    )
```

Should I be retrieving the top posts somewhere else? Is it retrieving the posts before the new field is added to the model? Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Can you expose your models ? Would be a bit clearer to debug then. And also the fields you're trying to add.

Comment: @bad_keypoints Yeah, totally. I've edited my post. Now that I've shared that, setting null=True on all of the fields probably isn't the best idea, although I don't necessarily need all of the Post objects to have all of those fields. Is there a way to set null=True by default without having to specify that for each field? What's the best way to handle that? Thanks so much for the reply.

Comment: You've to do it for every field.

Comment: Okay, I don't have a problem doing that, I just wasn't sure if those were best practices or not.